# ImportError: cannot import name UnrewindableBodyError when using certbot

Tags: python

When I am using this command in CentOS 7 to geneate a certificate:

```
yum install certbot
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==1.11.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2662, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import main as internal_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    from certbot import crypto_util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/crypto_util.py", line 32, in <module>
    from certbot import util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/util.py", line 24, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import constants
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/constants.py", line 6, in <module>
    from acme import challenges
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/acme/challenges.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InvalidURL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .request import make_headers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/request.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import UnrewindableBodyError
ImportError: cannot import name UnrewindableBodyError
```

seems the certbot using the python 2.7, but now my server is using python 3.6. what should I do to fix it? I have to use the python3. I have tried upgrade urllib3, but it seem did not work.

Comment: You installed it for python2.7. Try `pip3 install certbot`. Then probably `python3 -m certbot ...`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way and works:

```
pip3 install certbot
/usr/local/bin/certbot certonly -d '*.poemhub.top' --manual --preferred-challenges dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```